# Need a sane, Unity friendly vertex animation workflow

Tags: animation

v2.92. I need to animate a very simple mesh and I want to do it on the vertex level. One way or another the whole thing needs to get over to Unity in one piece. It's so simple that I don't want bones/armatures, I'm basically just moving one edge loop of a mesh along an axis while the other parts stay put, and rotating it a bit.

I am almost at wit's end, but I'll spare you further editorialization and just say what I've tried.

**Dope sheet** - Obviously I was trying to pair this with the other approaches listed, but I also tried the naive approach of just moving vertices around in Edit mode and learned the hard way that you can't key frame like that. I'm also not sure if an animation made via the dope sheet can be accessed in Unity for control via scripting/whatever.

**Shape Keys** - didn't work for me as I need more than one keyframe for the animation and my understanding of them is that each is based off the "base shape". There is an interesting view when turning off "Relative" shape keys where it looks like a multiple keyframe supported thing, but I couldn't get it working like I wanted. The constant flitting between Edit/Object mode absolutely mandated by the Shape Keys workflow also seemed like I was making a mistake.

**Animall** - this is the latest thing I tried and I think it will work but it is probably kind of resource intensive as it is storing info on every vertex even though higher transforms like entire mesh rotation are more efficient. And I'd be willing to accept that sin, but it also seems like a bad workflow with vertex animation because the animation will only play in Object Mode of the 3D Viewport, but I can only make vertex edits in Edit Mode. (Making edits accidentally in Object Mode applies it to the whole mesh, not the keyframe in the animation) It is not possible to get a 3D Viewport on one side of the screen in Edit Mode and one in Object Mode so this workflow again seems very poorly thought out for vertex editing. I am also not sure if it will be supported by Unity.

The worst part is not knowing what is supported or not in Unity. Many tutorials I have found refer to old Blender functionality or say X or Y thing isn't natively supported, but are 5 or more years old and could be flat out wrong nowadays. For all I know I could be missing a really simple clean solution that is relatively newer, hence the question. Worst case I can swallow my pride and try out one of the above workflows (but Animall is the only one so far that may go the distance to actually giving what I want and my confidence that Unity supports it is low).
So what can/should I use here, and what are the steps to get it into Unity once I have the animation ready?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if shape keys or Animall can be used in Unity. I think just using a single bone moving around and weight painting the verts to it would be the easiest. There's a point where the alternative "simpler" method is not so simple anymore. Ask me if you need instructions for setting up the bone.

Comment: I'm not averse to following tutorials on that so no worries there (I am more averse to picking the wrong approach and only learning it is wrong much later...) So I will try bone animation, but I may try in-engine vertex animation in Unity first to see if that is more workable. I'll come back with my results when I get a chance to do this all.